# Load in arbitrary code and find a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing an experiment that involves taking in an arbitrary bit of code and determining which class was just loaded from a `require <file>` or `eval <file>` statement.

So, for example, if I have:

```
module Foo
  class Bar < ExistingGemModule::ExistingGemClass

  end
end
```

I want to come up with Foo::Bar

Is there a way for me to do that?

These might be hacky ways to do it:

- Use regex on the file, including taking in modules/namespaces.
- Find an index of everything loaded before the statement, then immediately after, and perform `after - before`.

What I'm really checking if I can use bare-metal Ruby infrastructure/callbacks/interrupts/etc to do it.

Yes, I know it's dangerous to require arbitrary code in production. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Well you could eval the file contents and it will return the class/module object provided that the file only declares one class/module. You would also have to deal with the duplicate constant issue. But most autoloader designs are based on a set of conventions instead.

Comment: @max updated the question a bit. Eval returns a symbol of the last method declared in the class.